# "Средство агитации людей". Последнее слово — лишнее?

Tags: грамотная-речь

> "Средство агитации людей" или "средство агитации"?

Answer (score 2):

Правильно: **средство агитации.**

Агитация всегда обращена к людям, поэтому слово ***людей*** лишнее.

Примеры:

На достижение этого нужно нацелить все **средства агитации и пропаганды**. [// «Техника - молодежи», 1977]

Богатейшие **средства агитации**, которыми располагает наше государство, ― кино, радио, печать и т. д. [ «Советское искусство». № 5 (585), 1939]

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Comment: *Агитация всегда обращена к людям* — это в жизни, а в литературе (например, в фантастической) — не всегда.

Comment: в моем случае речь как раз идет о жизни))))

Answer (score 1):

Можно было бы предположить, что слово **агитация** было образовано в рамках русского языка как отглагольное существительное (от **агитировать**), однако практика употребления этих слов с зависимым существительным противоречит такому предположению; известно также, что слово "**агитатор**" пришло в русский независимым путём - из немецкого через французский. В сочетании с глаголом существительные в винительном падеже употреблялись в прошлом (революционном, до эпохи реальных выборов) достаточно широко: **агитировать рабочих, крестьян**, даже "**людей**". А вот у существительного **агитация** сочетаний с другим существительным в винительном падеже **не** встречается: можно найти книжные примеры выражения "**агитация рабочих**", но во всех случаях там оказывается *родительный падеж*, т. е. смысл в "агитации *со стороны* рабочих" (см. пример ниже). Это объясняет, почему смысл глагола словари выводят из существительного (*агитировать* = *заниматься агитацией*), а не наоборот (любопытно, что некоторые словари, видимо, на этом основании, трактуют глагол как непереходный). Соответственно, ни людей, ни фантастических существ в качестве прямого (вин. падеж) "*объекта агитации*"  быть **не должно**. Книжные примеры:

> *Очень интересно было бы посмотреть, как барышня в таком виде пришла бы
> **агитировать рабочих** и что бы они ей сказали.*
> [А. А. Ахматова. Автобиографическая проза (1957-1965)]
>
> *Я стал **агитировать рабочих** за Нарвской заставой и на Бумагопрядильной,
> создавать кружки, тройки и пятерки.*
> [П. А. Моисеенко. Воспоминания старого революционера (1921-1923)]
>
> *Большую роль в переломе настроения среди солдат сыграла коллективная
> **агитация рабочих**...*
> [Московский совет рабочих депутатов в 1917 году, Е. Игнатов, 1925]

Answer (score 0):

Агитация — это распространение идей. Может быть агитация среди определённой группы людей, соответственно средства агитации среди разных групп могут быть различны. В таком контексте можно говорить о **средствах агитации *среди* каких-то людей** (например, среди людей старшего поколения). "Агитация кого-то" не является литературной нормой, но допустимо в разговорной речи.

Для более полного ответа на вопрос необходимо иметь более широкий контекст фразы.

Comment: В моем случае речь как раз идет об обобщенном понятии "людей" - вообще. Поэтому никакой конкретики тут явно не нужно. Я не зря споткнулась взглядом об это словосочетание и захотела выкинуть лишнее слово. А вы утвердили меня в моем желании)))